# How to Lock A Remote PC for Not to be logged by users

Tags: windows, remote, user-profiles, lock

After the restart Remote PC, we need to run a VBScript on Remote PC before Users log in.
Becuase sometimes, users log in and VBScript doesnt work properly :( So Remote PC must be locked by us. How can we lock the Remote PC via cmd or vbs?

Please dont recommend us to use Pshell and Win Remote Desktop :)

We wonder if there is a way to lock Remote PCs via scripts :)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Lock" exactly?

Comment: how do you run the vbscript now?

Comment: Whats wrong with Powerscript exactly?

Comment: @techie007 I mean a vbs cleaning remote profiles

Comment: @Ramhound There is no wrong with Pshell but We work with VBS :)

Comment: I mean we dont want the users to log on/in PC when we run the script

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have the appropriate permissions on the machine, you could simply send the lock command to the box via Sysinternals [psexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897553.aspx)

Something along these lines:

`psexec \\machinename rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`

Assuming that is the type of "Locking" you are talking about.

Comment: Can we do this via CMD or VBS?

Comment: I don't know, have you tried? I can.

Comment: If I can I will do :) I dont know how to do via CMD :)

Comment: @serdar: psexec.exe is a program you have to run with a couple of parameters. How you accomplish that is up to you. You could use a shortcut on your Desktop to do it, if that suits your needs and abilities. Just link to the .exe and add some parameters so it locks the machine you want locked. Double click it when needed.